# Paper Trail Error After Upgrading Ruby 2.3.4 to 2.4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paper-trail-gem

Our system uses the paper_trail gem. At the time I upgraded my version of ruby from 2.3.4 to 2.4.2, I also upgrade the version of paper_trail from 7.0.3 to 8.1.0 This upgrade apparently introduced an incompatibility such that I no longer can read the versions created before the upgrade. If I create a new version after the upgrade, I can read that.

When I try to call previous_version or or version_at, I get this error:

`` TypeError: allocator undefined for Integer
from /Users/philiphallstrom1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:373:in `allocate' ``

Can you tell me how to update the previous versions so that they become accessible again? Thanks.

Comment: are you being forced to upgrade papertrail?

Comment: No, but even when I revert the version of paper_trail, it does not help. It seems like an incompatibility between ruby versions, which I am being forced to upgrade.

Comment: can you post your complete stacktrace?  right now it only shows a non-papertrail gem as the source